# Write a value from each row to every row x days ahead

Tags: r

I have the following following dataset:

```r
data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                   date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-01-04","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-10","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-04","2020-01-05")),
                   duration = c(2,3,4,2,4,3,4,2,2),
                   product = c("A","B","C","A","C","B","C","A","A"))
```

I have an id of people, what product they used on each day and also how long will the product last them (*duration*) - update: products in this sample do have a set duration, but in reality it does not to need to be the case.

I need to make a list of products that are currently in use by each person for each row, so the resulting dataset should look as such (separator is "|" here, but does not matter):

```r
data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
           date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-01-04","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-10","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-04","2020-01-05")),
           duration = c(2,3,4,2,4,3,4,2,2),
           product = c("A","B","C","A","C","B","C","A","A"),
           products_in_use = c("A","B","B | C", "A | B | C", "C", "B", "B | C", "A | B | C", "A | C"))
```

Basically I am thinking I would need to take all rows that are within *duration* days (as in less or equal days) from the current row and append to their list the current product. Then I would take a unique and ordered version of the list and write is as a string. But I dont know how to do the first step.

It would be preferred if all this would work inside of an dplyr pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see an *easy* way of doing this entirely within `dplyr` because it relies on checking the sum of the date and the duration in *each* row with the date in *every* row, but if you first define this function:

```r
get_products_in_use <- function(dates, durations, products)
{
  apply(sapply(seq_along(dates), 
         function(i) {
           ifelse(test = dates >= dates[i] & dates <= dates[i] + durations[i], 
                  yes  = products[i], 
                  no   = "")
           }),
      1, function(x) paste(unique(sort(x[nzchar(x)])), collapse = " | "))
}
```

Then it's very easy to use within a `dplyr` pipe:

```r
testdata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(products_in_use = get_products_in_use(date, duration, product))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id date       duration product products_in_use
#>   <dbl> <date>        <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          
#> 1     1 2020-01-01        2 A       A              
#> 2     1 2020-01-04        3 B       B              
#> 3     1 2020-01-06        4 C       B | C          
#> 4     1 2020-01-07        2 A       A | B | C      
#> 5     1 2020-01-10        4 C       C              
#> 6     2 2020-01-01        3 B       B              
#> 7     2 2020-01-02        4 C       B | C          
#> 8     2 2020-01-04        2 A       A | B | C      
#> 9     2 2020-01-05        2 A       A | C
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>